# How use Active Record pattern in TypeORM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typeorm

TypeORM provides examples for implementation in JavaScript (without typescript) [here](https://github.com/typeorm/javascript-example/blob/master/src/app3-es6/index.js).

The problem is, that only the Data Mapper pattern is described. In my current project, I want to use the Active Record pattern.

I have tried adding the `extend` or `target` properties pointing to `BaseEntity` (as string or object), but this is not working.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Define model and schema

(models/Nugget.js)

```
import typeorm from 'typeorm'
const { BaseEntity, EntitySchema } = typeorm

// "model"
export class Nugget extends BaseEntity {
    id;
    name;
}

// "schema"
export const NuggetSchema = new EntitySchema({
    name: "Nugget",
    target: Nugget, // the class above
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "int",
            generated: true
        },
        name: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
    }
})
```

Pass the schemas in entities when connecting

(dbConnect.js)

```
import typeorm from 'typeorm'
const { createConnection } = typeorm

import { NuggetSchema } from './models/Nugget'

const connection = await createConnection({
    type: db_type, // e.g. mysql
    host: db_host,
    port: db_port,
    database: db_database,
    username: db_user,
    password: db_pass,
    synchronize: false, // set to true to modify database to match schema
    logging: false,
    entities: [
        NuggetSchema
    ]
})
```

Import the model and use it to add/delete/query for that item (Active Record pattern)

(index.js)

```
import './dbConnect.js'

import { Nugget } from './models/Nugget'

const nugget = new Nugget()
nugget.name = "Hi, I'm A Nugget"
await nugget.save()

const nuggets = await Nugget.find({})
console.log('nuggets', nuggets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change model/Category.js to:

```
const BaseEntity = require("typeorm").BaseEntity;

class Category extends BaseEntity {
    constructor(id, name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Category: Category
};
```